# What is the way to perform the update operation in CRUD form?

Tags: reactjs

I have a students object defined in reactjs. My requirement is that when i click on the edit button, the details of the corresponding row should be updated in the `<input>` which I have successfully implemented.
The problem is when I am trying to update, I am getting an error as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/ToDo.js:92
  89 | <input type="text" name="email" className="item"  />
  90 | <button className="btn-add-item">Add</button>
  91 | </form>
> 92 | <table>{this.state.students.map(abc => (<tr><td>{abc.id}</td><td>{abc.name}</td><td>{abc.age}</td><td>{abc.email}</td><td>
     | ^  93 |  <button onClick={this.onDeleteHandle.bind(this, abc.id)}>Delete</button></td>
  94 |  <button onClick={this.onEditHandle.bind(this,abc.id,abc.name,abc.age,abc.email)}>Edit</button>
  95 |  </tr>))}</table></div>
```

My render method is as follows:

```
render() 

          {    
           return<div>
             {this.renderEditForm()}


                 <form  onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandle.bind(this)}>
                 <label >ID</label>
                   <input type="number"  name="id" className="item"  />
                 <label>Name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="item" className="item"  />
                   <label>age</label>
                   <input type="number" name="xyz" className="item"  />
                   <label>email</label>
                   <input type="text" name="email" className="item"  />
                   <button className="btn-add-item">Add</button>
                   </form>
                   <table>{this.state.students.map(abc => (<tr><td>{abc.id}</td><td>{abc.name}</td><td>{abc.age}</td><td>{abc.email}</td><td>
                    <button onClick={this.onDeleteHandle.bind(this, abc.id)}>Delete</button></td>
                    <button onClick={this.onEditHandle.bind(this,abc.id,abc.name,abc.age,abc.email)}>Edit</button>
                    </tr>))}</table></div>  
              }
            }
```

also the edit button follows the logic like below:

```
renderEditForm() {
    if (this.state.edit) {
    return <form onSubmit={this.onUpdateHandle.bind(this)}>
    <input type="text" name="updatedItem" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.id} />
    <input type="text" name="updatedItem1" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.name} />
    <input type="text" name="updatedItem2" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.age} />
    <input type="text" name="updatedItem3" className="item" defaultValue={this.state.email} />
    <button className="update-add-item">Update</button> 
    </form>    }  }
```

And the Update logic is as follows:

```
    onUpdateHandle(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({students: this.state.students.map(item => {
      if (item.id === this.state.id){
        item['id'] = event.target.updatedItem.value;        
        item['name']=event.target.updatedItem1.value;
        item['age']=event.target.updatedItem2.value;
        item['email']=event.target.updatedItem3.value;
      return item;}})})
      this.setState({edit: false});

  }
```

Please help.

Comment: validate your data ```<table>{this.state.students.map(abc => abc && (<tr><td>{abc.id}</td><td>{abc.name}</td><td>{abc.age}</td><td>{abc.email}</td><td>```

Comment: this is working partially....after the update it is showing only the record which is updated.My requirement is that it should show all other records as well which i have not updated including the record which got updated.

Comment: and aslo please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Please validate your data.

```
<table>{this.state.students.map(abc => abc && (<tr><td>{abc.id}</td><td>{abc.name}</td><td>{abc.age}</td><td>{abc.email}</td><td>
```

in your map function you are returning the one item, move the return statement outside the if statement.

```
onUpdateHandle = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const students = [...this.state.students];
  const studentState = this.state.students.map(item => {
    if (item.id === this.state.id) {
      item["id"] = event.target.updatedItem.value;
      item["name"] = event.target.updatedItem1.value;
      item["age"] = event.target.updatedItem2.value;
      item["email"] = event.target.updatedItem3.value;
    }
    return item;
  });
  this.setState({ edit: false, students: studentState });
};
```